# What security risks does the Test Access Port (TAP) introduce?

Tags: jtag, test, standard, security

Trying to get my head around the [JTAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG) world I looked at how the [Test Access Port (TAP)](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1149.1-2013.html) works and although I get why we need it, the diagram seemed to me (as a software developer) introducing some kind of backdoor to the architecture.

[image]

In the software world such mechanisms can be used in testing some parts of the software, however they get removed (hopefully) before the software is ready for release.

So the questions are:

- Doesn't TAP introduce security risks to the hardware?
- Are there standers to mitigate such risks if they exist?

Comment: In software though, gaining access to the hardware is considered "all hope is lost". Same applies here, when someone has the hardware in their hands, what is there they can not do with it?

Comment: @PlasmaHH - Usually but not always, consider PIC code protection or Apple secure enclave.

Comment: @pjc50: they just up the barrier, if you have enough resources you can get there too

Comment: So far the only known way of breaking into the secure enclave is via an exploit of the software on the other side, Apple vs FBI passim. It's a very high barrier.

Comment: Common on devices with internal flash is a setting which disables everything but whole-system erase, which becomes the only way to undo that setting.  The *intent* is that the system can be reprogrammed, but the old program cannot be extracted, or modified by someone who doesn't have an external copy of it.

Comment: @pjc: so what? With physical access to the chip, desolder it, solder in a different one. Only way to avoid that is having crypto routines that ensure authenticy, in the protected code area, which shouldn't be accessible, even via JTAG.

Comment: What use is replacing the chip with the keys that you want, with one that doesn't? Again, the model here is Apple vs FBI. Or maybe the smart card approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, TAP introduces hardware security risks. If you have access to the JTAG port you may be able to introduce false input/output.  However many chips provide a JTAG disable configuration that disables the JTAG after programming.

As far as risk mitigation, if you need such low level physical security you might consider choosing an IC that doesn't have this feature, or allows you to disable it.  Some disable signals are only a flash bit, and a full chip erase can restore JTAG access, others permanently alter the IC so JTAG will not be available after disabling it.

There are also implementations of encrypted JTAG, where you cannot use JTAG without the proper encryption and keys.

The 2009 paper, ["Attacks and Defenses for JTAG"](http://isis.poly.edu/~securejtag/design_and_test_final.pdf) provides significantly greater detail in the various means and ways that JTAG can be attacked, and defenses available.

Answer (score 4):

First, you're under the false impression that SW debugging mechanisms get removed from final products. For example check [Windows debugging API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): it has broad potential for abuse (reading other processes' memory and such) and none of it is needed by the final users.

Second, in order to exploit a hardware interface like JTAG, the attacker must have physical access to the system which usually means "game over" in terms of security. Even if the customer version of the product didn't have JTAG, nothing would stop the attacker from swapping the PCB with a custom one, which has whatever interfaces the attacker needs.

About the only real security issue arises when the developers want to protect themselves from malicious users who could abuse JTAG (for jail-breaking, firmware cloning etc). Relevant mechanisms for such protection are mentioned in other answers already - fuse bits, encryption keys etc. Of course, removing the programming/debugging interfaces completely would be more secure, but it would also be more expensive (e.g no in-system programming) and reduce the possibility of quality control.

JTAG in particular is used in End-Of-Line testing of PCBs, which makes sure that defective devices are not shipped to customers. That's the big difference compared to software world: if you have released a software, you don't have to test every copy of it before download. If you release hardware, you have to test every copy or assume the risk of production failures.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the ways in which users jailbreak phones: through the JTAG port. It does indeed let you access all the processor state and memory, and in some cases the contents of any internal ROM. This makes it very useful during production as a debugging feature.

Many systems will provide a "fuse" in the chip, which is a one-time-programmable device, to turn off JTAG access in such a way that it cannot be turned back on.